# php mysql update blob

Tags: php, mysql, string, binary, blob

New to PHP/mySql and having trouble inserting and retrieving binary data.  I have a mySql table called usr_pressdata.  The field 'BinDat' is of type mediumblob.

```
$dat = $this->parseOverview($sql);
    // $dat is now a binary string

$datsql = "Update usr_pressdata Set BinDat = " . $dat;
$datresult = mysql_query($datsql, $this -> conn) or die(mysql_error());

$getdat = "Select * from usr_pressdata";
$getdatresult = mysql_query($getdat, $this -> conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $getdatresult );
   $retval = $row['BinDat'];
```

In this example my goal is that $retval == $dat but it does not.  I suspect that my query string $datsql is incorrect.  Can someone correct this example code?  Thank you.

Comment: how are $retval and $dat different? did you try a var_dump() of both vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting values in a table (or more generally, when including a value in an SQL request):

1. the string must be enclosed between quotes ('...')
2. the string must be “escaped” using `mysql_real_escape_string` so as to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

So you need to write something like:

```
$request = "UPDATE usr_pressdata SET bindat= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($dat) . "';";
```

I suspect you may want to add a `WHERE someColumn = someCondition` clause at the end, because as it is now, it would affect all the rows in the table.

Comment: It is okay to affect all rows in the table.  There is only one row.

Comment: This sql request does not work for me.  Is mysql_real_escape_string a native method?

Comment: Yes, have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php